# How to send signals?

Tags: c

I created signals. One of them prints "1" 20 times. Another prints "2" 20 times.I want these signals to print their numbers in turn:1,2,1,2...But the program prints only "1".Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Well, What is the link between your loops and you signal handler?

Comment: I mean, you use sigset to set signal handlers in which you do nothing, then you use printf() from the main. Those has nothing to do with the signals you are catching...

Comment: sigset() defines a function as a signal handler. After using `sigset(SIGTERM,handler);` every SIGTERM sent to you program will execute `handler()` instead of killing you program.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use signals? Isn't it multi-threading that you want to do?

Comment: `Fork()` creates a new process which is different from a thread. Could you explain why you need to use signals? It seems you are confused about what signals are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92742/discussion-between-kotshi-and-dean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this code and see what when you send SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 to the pid printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void handler1(int signal)
{
   printf("Foo\n");
}

void handler2(int signal)
{
   printf("Bar\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("PID: %d\n", getpid());
    sigset(SIGUSR1,handler1);
    sigset(SIGUSR2,handler2);
    while (1);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @Dean Yes, google will tell you hundreds of way to do so.

Comment: Of course it is in a infinite loop,  (`while (1);`). I meant: "try to send signals from another terminal"

Comment: Use **ctrl+c** whenever you wanna kill the program.

Comment: Congrats, now try to understand why.